# free a malloc for two double pointers

Tags: c, pointers, malloc, free

In the main method I have this

```
    int **p1;
    int **p2;

    //malloc dynamically, let the array 2D [4][3]
    p1 = malloc(4 * sizeof(int*));
    p2 = malloc(4 * sizeof(int*));

    p2[0] = malloc(4 * 3 * sizeof(int)); 

    int i = 0;
    for(i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        p1[i]= malloc(3 * sizeof(int));
        p2[i + 1] = p2[i] + 3 * sizeof(int);        
    }

    initPtr(array,p1,p2);

    int m = 0;
    int n = 0;

    for (m; m < 4; m++) { 
        free(p1[m]);
    }
    free(p2[0]);
    free(p1);
}//end of main
```

problem comes when I free those memories I get invalid pointer munmap_chunk() error. If it helps, when I comment out the function call, block [1][2] and [3][2] has a value of 33 for p1, and all the rest is 0 including for p2 too. 
My method is as follows

```
void initPtr(int array[][3], **ptr1, **ptr2) {
    //here assign values for the dynamically allocated memory
    int i;
    int j;
    for (i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
            ptr1[i][j] = array[i][j];
            ptr2[i][j] = array[i][j];       
        }
    }
}
```

UPDATED:
This is the array declared in the main method

```
int array[4][3]={{0,1,2},{3,4,5},{6,7,8},{9,10,11}};
```

Comment: You allocate space for 4 `int*`s then write 5 `int*`s to it (through `p2`).

Comment: Please post the definition of `array`.

Comment: @chqrlie I do not understand what you meant. It is 2D array, and the first dimension is suppose to be dynamic, but for this example I am checking with value 4, so array[4][3], it is actually array with values in each block

Comment: `p2[i + 1] = p2[i] + 3 * sizeof(int);` probably doesn't do what you think it does... you're probably out of bounds already on the first loop iteration. (adding 1 to an `int *` increases the address by `1 * sizeof(int)`, not by just 1)

Comment: @user1986244: you didnt post a complete compilable example.  The missing parts may contain inconsistent definitions.  You use `array` in the `main` function but do not provide the definition. I'm just asking you to modify your question to include the definition of `array` to verify that it is indeed `int array[4][3] = { ... };`

Comment: C does not support _methods_. Only _functions_. And there is no 2D array in your first code and nothing which can be used as one or point to a 2D array! A pointer is not an array! Questions are required to provide a [mcve]. See [ask].

Comment: @olaf thanks question is answered already but I will be clear next time

Answer (score 2):

In the initialization loop, you write past the end of the allocated array:

```
p2[i+1] = p2[i] + 3 * sizeof(int);
```

when `i` is `3`, you write to `i[4]`. And you should just increment by 3 for each row, not `3 * sizeof(int)`.  `p2[i] + 3` means the address of the 4th `int` in the array pointed to by `p2[i]`.

It is better to initialize `p1` and `p2` in separate loops:

```
// initialize p1 with separately allocated arrays
for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
    p1[i] = malloc(3 * sizeof(int));
}

// initialize p2 with a single array with internal pointers
p2[0] = malloc(4 * 3 * sizeof(int)); 
for (int i = 1; i < 4; i++) {
    p2[i] = p2[i - 1] + 3;
}
```

You also forget to `free` `p2` at the end of `main`.

Comment: I still getting invalid pointer error  with that edit too

Comment: @user1986244: sorry about this, the arithmetic in the initialization of `p2` was incorrect, you should just add `3`, not `3 * sizeof(int)`

Comment: thank you, that worked for me, and I am trying to grasp the whole process again I will ask more

Comment: my understanding is that I have been moving the pointer by number of bytes, instead of moving it to the first index of the next block of array. i hope I make sense.

Comment: @user1986244: actually, neither describes the effects of adding an integer to a pointer: `p2[0]` points to an array of `int`. It points to the first element o the array, the one at index `0`. `p2[0] + 1` points to the second element, the one at index `1`, that you can read with `p2[0][1]`, and write with `p2[0][1] = 1;`.  `p2[0] + 3` points to the fourth element of the array.  Since you allocated 12 `int`s, you want `p[0]` to point to the first, `p2[1]` to point to the fourth, `p2[2]` to the seventh and `p2[3]` to the tenth.  You are constructing an indirect array pointing to a 2D array.

Comment: @user1986244 When you add a number - say `n` - to a pointer - say `p`, the resulting address is `original address (p)+ n * size of the pointed data type`.  i.e. The `* sizeof(datatype)` is implicit - you DONT have to mention it; if you mention it the final result will be `original address + n * sizeof(datatype) * sizeof(datatype)`. So if you have an `int *p` and you want third integer from that, you will do `p + 3`, and NOT `p + 3 * sizeof(int)`. This is called `pointer arithmetic`. A good tutorial in `pointer arithmetic` should clarify this concept.

Comment: thank you both of you for the explanation. More practice it will get in to my head

Comment: @chqrlie I did vote on your response, what else should I do?

Comment: @user1986244: you can accept the answer by clicking on the grey checkmark below the answer score. Thank you.